# Boostrap how to align vertical pill

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap and I am having several problems when trying to display a vertical pill.

I am trying to figure out how to display any output on the very top instead of on the bottom.

[This is how I want it to be displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsLY3.png) The vertical pill is displayed at the bottom but I want it to display on very top.

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 pull-lg-8 text-xs-center">
  <img src="img/150.png" class="m-x-auto img-fluid img-circle" alt="avatar" />
  <h6 class="m-t-2">Upload a different photo</h6>
  <label class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
    <span class="custom-file-control">Choose file</span>
  </label>
</div>

<!-- Vertical Pill Start -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Vertical Pill End -->

  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab" <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">First name</label>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <input class="form-control" id="" type="text" value="First Name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Middle name</label>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <input class="form-control" id="" type="text" value="Middle Name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Last name</label>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <input class="form-control" id="" type="text" value="Last Name">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean "horizontally" at the top? Because as per screenshot, it seems it would be more suitable with a horizontal pill

Comment: i want to keep the horizontal pill stay at its position and when it press it would display at top and fill the blank space is that possible?

Comment: Um..I'm not really sure what you meant by that. Could you clarify that again please? Do you want the pills horizontal or vertical and where is the blank space supposed to be? The red rectangle, right?

Comment: when i press vertical pill it display as the same position as the vertical pill but what i want is it would use space at top and fill it input text. since the input text at the bottom i can't add any more label or input text.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this hope this is helpful.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 ">
            <img src="img/150.png" class="m-x-auto img-fluid img-circle" alt="avatar" />
            <h6 class="m-t-2">Upload a different photo</h6>
            <label class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
                <span class="custom-file-control">Choose file</span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab"
                    <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">First name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <input class="form-control" id="" type="text" value="First Name">`enter code here`
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Middle name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <input class="form-control" id="" type="text" value="Middle Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Last name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <input class="form-control" id="" type="text" value="Last Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Vertical Pill End -->


    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i can't click your link still can't click your link

Comment: still can't click your link ?

Comment: @vinay i'm sorry i can't vote need 15 more points :( sorry already click it thank you